# Repopulate input fields when validation fails in update a row Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Is there any way to repopulate input fields when validation fails in update any row? I know I can do it with laravel form model binding, but i dont want to use it. I can populate form from database table when update row. I want to repopulate the form with old input when validation fails in update not with database value. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the `old()` helper. It is used this way:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?= old('username', 'default value') ?>">
```